# Adding Annotations to Landscape PDF Using iText

Tags: annotations, itext, landscape, portrait

my code creating annotations in pdf works ok

but i encountered a pdf where pages are displayed in landscape (1224x729) and the page's media box is vertical (729x1224) with a rotation value of 270

my coordinates for creating annotations is based on a bounding box area of 1224x729 so when it gets created the annotations are misplaced

is this still possible using iText? or the problem itself is the pdf when created?

Comment: I figure this is how it always is and that iText's convenience method of getPageSizeWithRotation() is the correct method to use.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't show your code. Depending on the options used for an annotation the admissions behave differently on rotated pages!

Comment: hi mkl i verified that getPageSizeWithRotation() is correct and gives the correct dimension. annotations are also placed correctly. however since rotation is 270 i have to rotate annotations in order for their display to be correct. im not sure what options youre referring to. ill research more on that and get back